# How to register minimum routes for similar actions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have some actions:

```
public partial class MyController : Controller
{    
     public ActionResult Action1()
     {              
     }
     public ActionResult Action2(int id)
     {              
     }

     public ActionResult Action3(string id)
     {              
     }

     public ActionResult Action4(string name)
     {              
     }
}
```

Do I need register routes for each action like this:

```
 routes.MapRoute("r1", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { id = UrlParameter.Optional });   
 routes.MapRoute("r2", "{controller}/{action}/{name}", new { name = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Or there is some way to register one pattern route for all actions or maybe I need some kind of "hack"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar urls should use similar routes. So in this case you have only a single url pattern which is `/controller/action/someid`. So simply use the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

and then update your actions:

```
public partial class MyController : Controller
{    
     public ActionResult Action1()
     {              
     }
     public ActionResult Action2(int id)
     {              
     }

     public ActionResult Action3(string id)
     {              
     }

     public ActionResult Action4(string name)
     {              
     }
}
```

As far as the last action is concerned the `name` parameter could be passed as query string. If you really insist on it being part of the path, you could rename it to `id`. It is better to pass arbitrary strings such as names as query string parameters and not as part of the url paths.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to register these extra url parameters...
If you make a form with 3 input controls and give them a name, then you make a action with the same names as the input controls. They will be magicaly filled in.

If you use strongly typed views, you can even pass models als input:

```
public class customer
{
    public int Id { get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

In your controller:

```
public ActionResult UpdateCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    // Add update logic
}
```